# Only one IF ELSE statement working SAS

Tags: sas

Can someone explain to me why only the first IF ELSE statement in my code works? I am trying to combine multiple variables into one.

```
DATA BCMasterSet2;
SET BCMasterSet;
drop PositiveLymphNodes1; 
if PositiveLymphNodes1 = "." then PositiveLymphNodes =   
put(PositiveLymphNodes2, 2.);
else PositiveLymphNodes = PositiveLymphNodes1;
if PositiveLymphNodes2 = "." then new_posLymph = put(PositiveLymphNodes, 
2.);
else new_posLymph = PositiveLymphNodes2;
RUN;
```

Here is a nice screenshot of what the incorrect output looks like:[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ26P.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing all of your data, but I have a suspicion:  is `positivelymphnodes1` character or numeric?  Is it ever actually equal to `"."`?

If you are trying to say "if PositiveLymphNodes1 is missing", then you can say that this way:

```
if missing(positivelymphnodes1) then ...
```

You can also do the same thing using `coalesce` or `coalescec` (the latter is character, the former numeric, in its return value).  It chooses the first nonmissing argument. - so if the first argument is missing, it chooses the second.

```
positiveLymphNodes = coalescec(PositiveLymphNodes1, put(positiveLymphNodes2,2.));
new_posLymph = coalescec(positiveLymphNodes2, put(positiveLymphNodes,2.));
```

I would be curious why you're using `put` only in one place and not the other - use it in both or neither, I would suggest.

Comment: I will try your suggestions out and let you know how it works. All variables are categorical with values of 1 = yes and 2 = no. The PUT is used in both IF ELSE statements, so I'm not sure what you mean. Did you not see it both times? For clarification, there are three columns that contain whether the patient had positive lymph nodes or not, and type = Char. Since they all contain the same information, I'm trying to combine them into one, and if one has missing data and the other doesn't, then overwrite the missing data with the non-missing data.

Comment: It appears PositiveLymphNodes1 and PositiveLymphNodes2 does not have "." for missing values. Let me go figure out how to fix this. Man, I can't wait until I know how to use SAS well enough that I don't have so much trouble with it.

Comment: `.` is only for numerics (and even then, it doesn't have to be - you can set the default missing character to be anything, including space, and space is quite common).  Always better to use `missing()` function especially when unsure of the type of the variable.  (SAS doesn't have "categorical" type, just numeric or character).

Comment: This worked perfectly using the COALESCEC statement. Thanks again, Joe!

Comment: And as far as the `put`, you don't use it consistently.  Just putting it in the `ELSE` isn't enough - if it's actually needed (I bet it isn't) then you need it in 3 of the 4 statements (everything except the one where you assign the value of the recently created variable from the 1st block into the 2nd block).